# How to load data from edge node to Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I have two servers A (edge node) and B (Hadoop cluster).
I need to move directories from A to B (Hadoop location).
I am able to copy to B cluster local but don't know exact command to copy to hdfs location in B Server

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
hadoop fs -put <local_src> <hdfs_src>
```

Refer to [this](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/) for further assistance. Also to see what commands are available to you on the CLI:

```
hadoop --help
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the two :

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/username/abc.txt  /user/username/
```

where /home/username/abc.txt is file on your edge node and /user/username/ is directory on hdfs where you want to copy the file.

OR

```
hadoop fs -put /home/username/abc.txt  /user/username/
```

where /home/username/abc.txt is file on your edge node and /user/username/ is directory on hdfs where you want to copy the file.